# Slow network connections using Hyper-V core 2012 R2 on HP Proliant DL380 G8

Tags: networking, hyper-v, tcp

I'm experiancing slow network connections from HP Proliant DL380 G8 servers using Broadcom 1 Gb/s Network adapter. The network speed is faster when towards the system then outgoing network connections. The system is running Microsoft Hyper-V core 2012 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to install the correct network adapter driver. The correct driver can be found here : http://h20564.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5177954&swItemId=MTX_d07f1f998bcc40f2a912f37c7f&swEnvOid=4168